# Mysql WHERE optional

Tags: mysql

if i have an example table like

```
id || value_a
```

I want to select 5 entries where value_a = 1.
Quite simple so far, but now if there are less results than 5, i want to still have 5 results. So if there are 3 entries with value_a = 1, then I want to get those 3 results and 2 other ones where value_a can be anything. How can i achieve this in the best way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can order by the result of a comparison calculation, like so:

```
SELECT stuff FROM table ORDER BY (value_a = 'value you want') DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: very nice! works fine, cant accept answerright now, it tells me i have to wait 8 minutes, but will do then.

Answer (score 1):

```
(
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   value_a = 1
LIMIT 5
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   value_a <> 1
LIMIT 5
)
ORDER BY
        value_a = 1 DESC
LIMIT 5
```

This will use an index on `value_a` efficiently